# How to explode an HTML element with jQueryUI's explode effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I can't seem to make the jQueryUI explode effect work. Here's [a jsfiddle I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/P4JXx/3/). Usually when I try the element hides with no explosion effect whatsoever, the jsfiddle just looks strange exploding.

```
$('h1, h2').click(function() {
    $(this).hide('explode');
});
```

The [jQueryUI docs on the explode effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/) are not very clear on how to use it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I modified your example a little bit by adding a background, width, and height to the <div>, targeting the <div> in jQuery instead of the "h1, h2", and it looks like its exploding correctly. I think your original fiddle behaves strangely because of the small size of the <h1> and <h2> - there's not much animation besides a letter blipping off left quickly.

Comment: you need more content in the element to show the exploding effect, http://jsfiddle.net/P4JXx/6/, otherwise all you will see is the exploding effect of the top corner, which is the blipping off that smclark89 refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by putting more text. Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k380zpgx/. By the way use this code instead it gives you more control of the effect.

```
$('h1, h2').click(function() {
    $(this).hide( "explode", {pieces: 16 }, 2000);
});
```